# How to include subdirectories in gulp task

Tags: gulp

I am just getting started with Gulp.

I have this:

```
var path = require('path');
var appRoot = 'src/';
var outputRoot = 'dist/';

module.exports = {
root: appRoot,
source: appRoot + '**/*.js',
html: appRoot + '**/*.html',
style: 'styles/**/*.css',
output: outputRoot,
doc:'./doc',
e2eSpecsSrc: 'test/e2e/src/*.js',
e2eSpecsDist: 'test/e2e/dist/'
```

};

This pathing is used to convert the source files from ES6 to ES5, and then drop in them in the dist directory.  This all works fine.

However, it only takes the files from the src directory, not subfolders.  How do I include the subfolders such as src\dir1 and src\dir2?

Comment: src/**/*.js should take care of all js files in all subfolders.

Comment: @rbaghbanli, thank you that works.  If you post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

src/**/*.js should take care of all js files in all subfolders.